# How do I prevent 2 js files to be overwrite in my HTML code?

Tags: javascript, html, overwrite

How do I prevent 2 .js files to be overwrite in my html code?
I have 2 .js files one for scroll bars and another one for dropdown menu.
when I import both files in my template code, the first one won't work (second one will overwrite the first one).

I'm confused how to prevent this and make both working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, overwrite is not the correct word for it. They might be conflicting eachother, due to global variables having the same name, perhaps. It's impossible to find out what the problem is, without looking at them...

jQuery and MooTools are known for interfering with eachother. You should use, in YOUR code, before anything else:
In the begining of you login.js file put the following line:

```
var J = jQuery.noConflict();
```

and replace every $ for J

then, on scroll.js, where you see this at the end:

```
window.addEvent('domready', function(){             
    // -- first example, vertical scrollbar --
    makeScrollbar( $('scrollbox'), $('scrollbar'), $('handle') );
});
```

replace the makeScrollbar line for

```
makeScrollbar( J('#scrollbox')[0], J('#scrollbar')[0], J('#handle')[0] );
```

It should work fine but, as i said, you should look for a solution that uses only jQuery or Mootools

Comment: 2 first links are for scrollbars and 3rd one is for dropdown menu

Comment: at first glance, scroll.js invokes window.addEvent(), this doesn't exist. it should be window.addEventListener()

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm new to javascript and jquery. You mean I have to make variable called J and then replace all $s in .js files with J ?

Comment: first of all, just try replacing  window.addEvent() with window.addEventListener() in the scroll.js.  if it doesn't work, yes, try that

Comment: and you should not replace $ for J on mootools and jquery file

Comment: I've replaced addEvent with addEventListener but it doesn't work.

Comment: Where should I add var J = jQuery.noConflict(); exactly? in all js files? Please explain more and guide me how to replace $s .

Comment: can you paste your HTML page to pastebin.com?

Comment: I've checked in FF8,IE8 & Chrome

Comment: i don't get it... here you are only including jQuery. no mootools, no login.js

Comment: welll, i've come up with a solution, this is definitely because of conflicts with the two libraries... it works for this page, but you should look into trying to use only jQuery or only Mootools... I'll post it as an edit to my answer

Comment: var J = jQuery.noConflict() goes in the begining of login.js file, and all the $s in that file must change to J

Comment: and remove var J = jQuery.noConflict() from the scroll.js file

Comment: you have to replace all dollars for Js in login.js

Comment: WoW, It's working! :) Thank you so much Andre. I never forgot your helps. Many Many Thanks :X